# stating quote as "quote" in sqldf

Tags: r, quote, sqldf

I have a csv file which `sep="\t", quote=TRUE`, so the data is quoted like `"2011-01-11"`

I used the following script to import the csv file into R

`temp <- sqldf("select * from dummy limit 10",file.format=list(header=TRUE,sep="\t",quote="\""))`

But it gives me something like `"\"2011-01-11\""`

The `\"` is the extra thing in each cell that I want to get rid of, how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Its a FAQ:  [How does one deal with quoted fields in read.csv.sql?](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#13._How_does_one_deal_with_quoted_fields_in_read.csv.sql_?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with sqldf, but there must be a better way importing your dataset. However, an answer to your question:

```
x <- c("\"2011-01-11\"")
gsub("\\\"", "", x)
```

Comment: The problem is not what is used as a separator.